# javascript code bing search - get more than 30 results

Tags: javascript, python, hyperlink, urllib2

I am doing a search over the bing search webpage. Assume I search for the term "Julia Roberts", then the url with the results is roughly the following one:

```
http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=julia+roberts
```

As I am downloading the code using python, I use the following source:

```
import urllib

def geturl(link,my_file):
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, my_file)
    except:
        pass

link = "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=julia+roberts"
my_file = "my_file.txt"

get_url(link,my_file)
```

The problem is, such source includes only the first 30 results (or 50).

***How do I get the source that includes, say, the 200 first results?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you expecting below result , please try in your console window for

"http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=julia+roberts" for this page.

**JS:**

```
var a=document.querySelectorAll('div a img');

for(i in a){
console.log(a[i].src); // get all the image source src path
//console.count("called"); // it will retrieve 246 image src path 
}
```

Comment: hi there, thanks a lot. I was actually copying the source manually. In reality, I am looking to downlaod the source pro-grammatically. I use mostly python, so I wish I could use python. I will reframe the question

Comment: hi Codeman, it was indeed helpful, so I accepted the answer :) - but if you know how to programmatically get 246 images in Python, I would highly appreciate if you can post it! :)

Comment: @AlejandroSimkievich : Thanks for accepting the answer. I have no idea on python. please find below links "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350464/extract-image-links-from-the-webpage-using-python" and "https://unreachable2027.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/python-script-to-grab-all-images-in-a-webpage/" may be this will be useful :)