# Extracting image links from the webpage using Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I find this query 
[Extract image links from the webpage using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350464/extract-image-links-from-the-webpage-using-python)

can someone tell the syntax(regarding to first answer) for the case when image can be composed with numbers and small letters too?

every image name is an abbreviation composed by capital letters, so...

```
for link in re.findall('http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/nba/logos/30x30/[A-Z]*.png', source):
```

Comment: instead of this [A-Z]* use [A-Za-z0-9]+

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how regular expression works. The [A-Z]* in your question code says: "Every name with capital letters, whatever the number of capital letters is".

Here you find the Documentation for python [2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [3.X](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) on how to use Regex.

For example if you replace `[A-Z]*` with `.*` you will get all images in format .png.

```
for link in re.findall('http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/nba/logos/30x30/.*\.png', source):
```

The backslash on `\.png` escapes the dot, because else this could be every character. If you just need to handle capital/small letters and numbers you could do this as well:

```
for link in re.findall('http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/nba/logos/30x30/\w*\.png', source):
```

This will allow A-Z + a-z + 0-9 + _

Hope this will help you.